# Angular material button always has a grey background anytime the modal is opened

Tags: angular-material

I have an Angular Material modal that opens, but after it opens, the `Go Back button`, which is a **mat-button**, always has a gray background. However, when I click outside the modal, it disappears. How do I remove the grey background.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `Material`s autoFocus property. Disable it like this:

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
      autoFocus: false
    });
```

`autoFocus: false` does the trick.

**autoFocus: TRUE** (default)
[image]

**autoFocus: FALSE**
[image]